# Changing WordPress link in header

Tags: wordpress

I have made a website that has 2 WordPress installs one for English language and one for Irish language. They are identical setups with same categories, page names etc.

I have 'English | Irish' links in my header on each page.

When you are on the english page and you click the 'irish' link at top I would like it to take you to the same page but on the Irish site.

The link structure is shown below:

http://mysite.com/english/about

http://mysite.com/irish/about

So I really only need 'english' in the url to be replaced by 'irish'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their are standard wordpress plugins that handle multi-language issue's for you. But if you whant to stay with you choise this script does exactly what you asked.

```
$url = 'http://www.mysite.com/english/about/me/test';

$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
$path_parts = explode("/",$parsedUrl[path]);

$newUrl = $parsedUrl[scheme] . "://" . $parsedUrl[host];
foreach($path_parts as $key =>$part){
    if($key == "1"){
        if($part == "english") $newUrl .= "/irish";
        else $newUrl .= "/english";
    } elseif($key > "1"){
        $newUrl .= "/" . $part;
    }
}

echo "Old: ". $url . "<br />New: " .$newUrl;
```

Comment: Plus 1 for going to the trouble of writing the specific code.

Comment: Actually, one little change. You'll need to add the rest of the path to the end of $newURL since "I would like it to take you to the same page but on the Irish site". I'm writing a bit of an update to mine where I'm doing this.

Comment: I allready do that in the part

     elseif($key > "1"){
        $newUrl .= "/" . $part;

If you run the code you see that it does that already

Comment: I've expanded mine anyway (since I was already doing it). Two things of note: 1) using switch with default should catch all cases and 2) you can eliminate a foreach with implode (which probably offers a negligible performance difference).

Comment: Argh! I hate how you can't edit comments after 5 min! Just for clarity on my first point, I meant that you can add "n" number of cases for languages and still have a default option (which is slightly more efficient than writing a bunch of elsifs). In this case there are only ever 2 cases, so we don't care.

Comment: You are right about the performance difference, the use of implode is faster then the use of explode with foreach. But i tested the difference and its 1,4 microseconde so 0,0000014 seconde. In this case i don't think it really makes a difference...

Comment: Things that change in 1.4 microseconds http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.4+microseconds *grin*

Answer (score 0):

Are you using localization - see http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers and http://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress? If so, see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_locale. You can use this to detect the locale and update the link accordingly. If you're using a plugin, you should check the plugin documentation.

If not, you could parse the current URL and explode the path, then update the link this way - http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Example:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.domain-name.com/english/index.php/tag/my-tag';

$path = parse_url($url);
// split the path
$parts = explode('/', $path[path]);
//get the first item
$tag = $parts[1];
print "First path element: " . $tag . "\n";

$newPath = "";
//creating a default switch statement catches (the unlikely event of) unknown cases so our links don't break
switch ($tag) {
    case "english":
        $newPath = "irish";
        break;
    default:
        $newPath = "english";
}

print "New path element to include: " . $newPath . "\n";

//you could actually just use $parts, but I though this might be easier to read     
$pathSuffix = $parts;

unset($pathSuffix[0],$pathSuffix[1]);

//now get the start of the url and construct a new url
$newUrl = $path[scheme] . "://" . $path[host] . "/" . $newPath . "/"  . implode("/",$pathSuffix) . "\n";
//full credit to the post below for the first bit ;)
print "Old url: " . $url . "\n". "New url: " . $newUrl;
?>
```

Adapted from http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-186104.html